# Filtering on a one-to-many relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, filter

I have a question regarding filtering in MySQL. I have two tables one with members and one with membership data. I like to be able to join the two tables and be able to filter on:

- members that still have an active membership (date of October 6th 2020 as reference date)
- memebers that do not have an active membership anymore

Can anyone give me the correct SQL code the filter on this? I am not realy good in this more advanced SQL statements. Many thanks in advance!

Members

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   Name     |
+----+------------+
| 01 | Gerico     |
| 02 | Stefan     |
+----+------------+
```

Membership

```
+----+------------+-------------+------------+
| ID | MemberID   | From        | To         |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+
| 01 |         01 | 01/01/1990  | 01/01/2000 |
| 02 |         01 | 01/01/2005  | 31/12/2154 |
| 03 |         02 | 01/01/1990  | 01/01/2000 |
| 04 |         02 | 01/01/1992  | 31/12/1999 |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what have you tried and explain how/where it failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why the [tag:double] tag? There seems to be no relation to that datatype here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Define the term "active membership" precisely. For example, if a member has 2 rows in membership, one from 2010 till 2015, and another from 2025 till 2030 - does this member is active now, in 2020?

Comment: The SQL statement for the real tables (Dutch) is as follows: 

SELECT DISTINCT if(`Voorvoegsels`="",`Achternaam`,CONCAT(`Voorvoegsels`," ",`Achternaam`)) AS `Achternaam`,if(`Voornaam`="",`Voorletters`,`Voornaam`) AS `Voornaam`,`Geboortedatum`,CONCAT(`Adres`," ",`Huisnummer`) AS `Adres`, `Plaats`, `PeriodeTot` FROM `schut_leden` left join `schut_lidmaatschap` on schut_leden.ID=schut_lidmaatschap.IDLid left join `schut_adres` on schut_leden.ID=schut_adres.IDLid where `PeriodeTot`<curdate() in (select `PeriodeTot` from `schut_lidmaatschap` where `PeriodeTot`<>'2154-12-31') order by `Achternaam`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming an active member is one who has a membership whose date range includes the current date. Then to select active members:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Members.* FROM
Members JOIN Membership ON Members.ID = Membership.MemberID
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN Membership.`From` AND Membership.`To`
```

(A `SELECT DISTINCT` is done in case a member has multiple, overlapping memberships.)

Or you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM Members
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT ID FROM Membership WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN `From` AND `To` AND MemberID = Members.ID
)
```

To select non-active members:

```
SELECT * FROM Members
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ID FROM Membership WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN `From` AND `To` AND MemberID = Members.ID
)
```

[See db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQ2aLyj9gBFsVwCuo85cC5/0)

The comment made by @Strawberry refers to the responsibility of the OP to create the above db-fiddle or equivalent for people to be able to test against us.